# Use result of find command as file-name for stdout

Tags: bash, terminal, base64

I'm using the commandline to convert PNG images to a Base64-encoded string. What I'd like to do is to use `find` to do this on an entire directory.

```
find ./ -name "*.png" -exec base64 > out.txt {} \;
```

Rather than storing all the results in one text-file, I'd like to be able to preserve a relation between source-file and result. For both solutions I'm clueless:

1. Store matched file-name and the Base64-encoded result in one text-file for all matches (e.g. my_file.png = `<base64-string>`).
2. Create a text-file for each result, with the filename matching the base-name of the source PNG.

Does the `find` command offer to make use of it's matched filename through a variable? Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I well understand your problem, you want to convert each *.png file into a base64 one, preserving its name.
Now, this should do the trick:

```
find . -name "*png" -exec bash -c "base64 {} > {}.txt" \;
```

Now, let's say you have the files **a.png**  **b.png** and **c.png** in your directory. This command will output you:

```
a.png.txt
b.png.txt
c.png.txt
```

Where the files are the text files you need.

The problem you were experiencing was actually how to redirect the output within -exec in find, which was solved here: https://superuser.com/questions/231495/how-can-i-use-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-command-run-through-finds-exec

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I used the {} from an other find command I've been using, but wasn't aware it represents the result.