# Find command is not sending one file at a time to my php command

Tags: bash, find

I have a bunch of php files in a directory called `blog`, so it looks kind of like this:

```
./blog/hello.php
./blog/essay-for-english-class.php
./blog/research-for-south-american-reptiles.php
```

If I run a command like `cd blog && php hello.php`, I will see some json content, which is what I expect.  I want to run a bash command that outputs each php file's content to their own separate json file in a separate directory while also keeping a variation of the original file name.  So I tried something like this:

```
cd blog;
find ./ -iname "*.php" -exec php "{}" > "../build/blog/{}.json" \;
```

But the result is this:

```
cd ../build && ls;

{}.json
```

Only the `{}.json` file appears in the directory.  And it has **ALL** the php json content concatenated into one file.  This is not what I was expecting.

I was expecting:

```
../build/blog/hello.php.json
../build/blog/essay-for-english-class.php.json
../build/blog/research-for-south-american-reptiles.php.json
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Ideally I also want to remove the `.php` from the json file names as well.

Comment: The shell parses & applies the redirect before running `find`, do the entire output of `find` (and everything it runs) ends up in that single file. Does ["Use result of find command as file-name for stdout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294635/use-result-of-find-command-as-file-name-for-stdout/20295016#20295016) answer your question? (Note: it's actually safer to pass the filename to `bash -c` as a separate argument; see [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1327969/appending-new-lines-to-multiple-files/1327980#1327980) for details.)

Comment: find ./ -name '*.php' -type f -exec bash -c 'for file do mkdir -p "$(pwd)/build" && cp "$file" "$(pwd)/build/$(basename ${file/.php*/.json})"; done' sh {} +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from Gordon and HatLess, this was my final solution:

```
cd blog;
find ./ -name '*.php' -type f -exec bash -c 'for file do php "$file" > "$(pwd)/../build/blog/$(basename ${file/.php*/.json})"; done' sh {} +;
```